# Excel understanding SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula that uses the below SUMPRODUCT:

> =SUMPRODUCT((Data!X:X = 0)* ((Data!H:H =A1)+IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A1, Data!J:J), 0), 1, 0))* (Data!U:U = A14)*(Data!M:M >= C2)*(Data!N:N
>   <=B3))

The issue I'm having is the with the OR part:

```
((Data!H:H =A1)+IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A1, Data!J:J), 0), 1, 0)).
```

The issue is it not working and I'm really not sure I'm going about this right. The logic I'm shooting for:

> if the value in A1 equals any data in cells Data!H:H use it,
>   **or
>   if not**, check Data!J:J.

any help would be great.

Comment: have you tried to evaluate this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: yes, I also checked to make sure that the data should show me a value. there is no data in Data!H:H =A1 but the name is in Data!J:J now in Data!J:J there are more than one name .. not sure if that's causing the problem

Comment: try this one: `=SUMPRODUCT((Data!X:X = 0)*(Data!U:U = A14)*(Data!M:M >= C2)*(Data!N:N <=B3)*IF((Data!H:H=A1)+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,Data!J:J)),1,0))` with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Wow that worked! but I don't understand the use of the ISNumber? please post this as a answer so I can give you credit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
            (Data!X:X = 0)*
            (Data!U:U = A14)*
            (Data!M:M >= C2)*
            (Data!N:N <=B3)*
            IF((Data!H:H=A1)+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,Data!J:J)),1,0)
  )
```

evaluates with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`SEARCH(...)` reutns either number either `#VALUE!`, so `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...))` gives you `TRUE` if value found and `FALSE` if value not found